# Do you know an Inno Setup wrapper that I can use in C#?

Tags: c#, inno-setup

I commonly use Inno Setup manually to build setups for my programs. Now I would like to write a program that can easily build various distributions of an other program, and in order to do that I'd liked to use Inno Setup by .NET code.

Do you know a way to use Inno Setup as an external library, or use a .NET wrapper or at least communicate with Inno Setup through command line?

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, your C# application would create the installer script, and then launch the command-line compiler to create the setup executable. This is explained in the [documentation](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/), specifically in the booklet `Other Information`, topic `Command Line Compiler Execution`.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, a .NET Wrapper for Inno Setup is available as a FREE and Open Source Project from SpiceLogic Inc. Here is the link

https://www.spicelogic.com/Blog/Inno-Setup-Net-Wrapper-8

It is an easy, ready to use Open Source C# class library.

Sample usage code snippet is provided below.

private void btnBuildInstaller_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Guid productGuid = Guid.NewGuid();

```
    SetupSettings innoSetupSetting = new SetupSettings
    {
        CompanyName = "Your Company Name",
        // A folder with this company name will be created in the Start Menu / Program Files folder
        //and your Product short cut will be placed within this Company Name folder.

        ProductName = "your Product Name", 

        ProductId = productGuid,
        // You should keep your product Guid Unique so that you can publish update easily with same Guid.

        ProductVersion = new Version("1.0.0.0"), // Your product version


        DeployableFolderPath = "C:\\My Project\\Deployable",
        // This folder contains all of the exe, dll etc whatever you want to publish to your user's computer. 
        // You do not need to specify each file name. Whatever file placed in this deployable folder will be 
        // published to your user's computer.

        StartUpApplictionFileName = "My Exciting Calculator.exe",
        // This is the main executive file name which will be placed in the Start Menu

        ShortCutName = "Exciting Calculator", // Well, this shortcut name will be shown in the start menu,
        //if  your product name is very big, it is better to use a short cut name to identify your product 
        // quickly and this property holds that short cut name.

        CompanyUrl = "http://your-company-website.com",

        SupportUrl = "http://your-company-website.com/ContactUs",

        IconFilePath = "C:\\My Project\\Resources\\my-icon.ico", // This icon will be shown in Desktop and Start Menu.

        EULAFilePath = "C:\\My Project\\Resources\\End-User-License-Agreements.txt",
        // If you set this property, only then a End User License Agreement Screen will be shown, otherwise no EULA screen will be shown.

        Platform = PlatformNames.AnyCPU_Prefer32Bit,
        // This property is self explanatory, you can set PlatformNames.AnyCPU, PlatformNames.x64, PlatformNames.x32 etc.
        // If you set value PlatformNames.x64 then your application will be installed in "C:\Program Files" folder. 
        // If you set value PlatformNames.x32, then your application will be installed in "C:\Program Files (x86)" folder. 
        // If you set value PlatformNames.AnyCPU, then, if your user's OS is Windows 64 bit, then your application will be
        // installed in "C:\Program Files" folder otherwise it will be installed in "C:\Program Files (x86)" folder.


        UninstallerFeedbackUrl = "http://your-company-website.com/uninstall-feedback",
        // If you set this property, then after uninstall, this url will be opened where you can ask your user to provide
        // additional feedback.

        GeneratedSetupScriptFolderPath = "C:\\My Project\\Temporary Scripts",
        // This folder is the place where InnoSetup Intermediate scripts will be generated. 
        // As you understand that, your C# code will generate Pascal Scripts for InnoSetup and 
        // finally that Pascal script will be executed to build your installer file. So, this 
        // folder will be used to store the auto-generated Pascal Scripts. You will never need to 
        // look inside this folder. Every time you call the BuildSetupFile(), old scripts will be 
        // deleted and new scripts will be written.


        OutPutSetupFilePath = "C:\\My Project\\Publish\\Setup.exe",
        // This is the path where your final Installer file will be created.
        // If a file already exists in this path then the existing file will be replaced.


        Prerequisites = new List<Prerequisite> // This is a collection of prerequisites. 
        // Prerequisites can be .NET Framework, SQL Express Local Db etc.
        // Every prerequisite can be configured to either install directly from Installer 
        // or Download from Web. IF you prefer to download from Web, then you can super configure
        // to define if the required prerequisite file should be downloaded automatically from a 
        // remote URL or it will simply navigate to a Download page and user can download the necessary
        // prerequisite from that page. For example, if you want to define .NET Framework 4.5 is a 
        // prerequisite for your application, then, you can navigate your user to the download page of 
        // Microsoft .net framework 4.5. 
        {
            new DotNetFrameworkPrerequisite(DotNetVersions.V4_5)
            // This example is a very basic common usage. Here we did not set any extra property of the DotNetFrameworkPrerequisite.
            // Therefore, by default, the installer will check if the .NET framework version 4.5 is installed in user machine or not.
            // If not, then, the installer will take the user to the official Microsoft .NET framework 4.5 download page.

            // You can set many properties of this class to customize the behavior. For example, you can host the .NET Framework in your 
            // own server and silently download and install to user's machine so that if the user wont be aware about what is .NET framework,
            // you wont risk missing the user's installation. Please check the documentation for details.
        },

        FileExtensionAssociation = ".abc",
        // Yes, if you want to associate any file that has extension *.abc with the start up application,
        // then, you set this property. That means if a file with extension *.abc is double clicked in user's PC,
        // then the exe file defined in the property StartUpApplictionFileName = "My Exciting Calculator.exe", will be 
        // invoked and the full file path of the double clicked file will be passed to this exe file as command argument.
        // So, you can program your application to receive this file path as command Argument.


        SignToolInfo = new SignToolInfo("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\8.0\\bin\\x64\\signtool.exe") 
        // The constructor takes the path to your SignTool.exe file.

        // Yes, you can program to Sign All Signable files (like exe and dll files) including the Uninstaller.
        // You read right. Yes, your uninstaller will be signed too, which is really an exciting and rare feature
        // in an installer software. If you do not want to digitally sign your files, then, do not set this SignToolInfo property.
        {
            PfxFilePath = "C:\\your-pfx-file-path.pfx",
            TimeStampServerUrl = "http://digicert.timestampserver.com", // a TimeStamp Server Url
            CertificateSubject = "Certificate Subject"
        },

        ShellContextMenuItem = new WindowsShellContextMenuItem
        // Another exciting feature is Windows Context Menu Shell Integration.
        // That means, you can right click on a file or folder and invoke your application.
        // If you do not want the Shell Integration, then do not set this property.
        {
            DisplayName = "Resize Image", // This text will be shown in the Context Menu

            // Say for example, your application is an Image Resizer application, then, you may want to 
            // allow the user to right click on an image type file to invoke the application.
            // If the user right click on an Image file and click the menu item 'Resize Image', 
            // then your startup exe application defined in the property StartUpApplictionFileName = "My Exciting Calculator.exe", will be 
            // invoked and the full file path of the double clicked file will be passed to this exe file as a command argument.
            // So, you can program your application to receive this file path as command Argument.

            TargetType = WindowsShellContextMenuItem.TargetTypes.FileWithExtensionConstraint,
            // This Target type can be WindowsShellContextMenuItem.TargetTypes.FileWithExtensionConstraint, 
            // WindowsShellContextMenuItem.TargetTypes.File or WindowsShellContextMenuItem.TargetTypes.Folder.
            // If you set WindowsShellContextMenuItem.TargetTypes.FileWithExtensionConstraint, that means,
            // The context menu will be shown on File but if the file has extensions defined in the array type 
            // property named ExtensionConstraints. IF you set WindowsShellContextMenuItem.TargetTypes.Folder
            // for this TargetType, then the ContextMenu will be shown on Folders only. If you set TargetType
            // = WindowsShellContextMenuItem.TargetTypes.File then the Context Menu will be shown on Any File type.

            ExtensionConstraints = new[] {  ".jpg", ".png"}
        },

    };


    // Ok, once we have setup various properties for the object  SetupSettings innoSetupSetting,
    // we can instantiate the  InnoSetupService and pass this Settings object to the constructor.

    InnoSetupService generator = new InnoSetupService(innoSetupSetting, innoSetupCompilerExePath: "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Inno Setup 5\\iscc.exe");
    // Yes, you need to pass your InnoSetup Compiler File Path. At the time of this writing, This wrapper library is working fine on Inno Setup 5. 
    // And it should work on future versions too. If this library stops to work on future version, then, as this wrapper library source code is open,
    // hopefully someone will come up with an upgrade which will work on the future version.


    // finally call the BuildSetupFile() method of InnoSetupService Class. This method will return a log string which 
    // is captured from the Console output of InnoSetup.
    string result = generator.BuildSetupFile();

    // If all goes good, then, your Setup exe file is built by this time and stored in the path you defined in the property
    // named OutPutSetupFilePath.

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't know if there is already some ready to run *InnoSetup* wrapper, but you can do easily (as long as you familiar with *InnoSetup*), just by using *command line* call technique mantioned by you in question. To do this just create an instance of [Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.diagnostics.process%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)  class, more or less like here:

```
Process innoProc = Process.Start(InnoSetupExePath, Arguments);
```

This is basically what you need, using one of the overloads of [Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/h6ak8zt5.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I have a c# class for the Inno compiler which uses the compiler API and supports getting progress and status information:
https://earlsoft.kilnhg.com/Repo/BuilderPro/Extensions/Inno/File/InnoCompiler.cs?rev=tip
It also allows the script to be "streamed in" savign haveing to write to disk.

Let me know if you find any bugs and I'll take a look.